# Create new column with values from multiple other columns chosen conditionally based on another column

Tags: r

I am trying to create a new variable that is populated by other columns based on the values in a third column. For instance, consider the data below:

```
x   our1    our2    our3    our4    our5    
4   10      50      40      30      20
1   20      10      50      40      30
3   30      20      10      50      40
2   40      30      20      10      50
5   50      40      30      20      10
```

I want to create a new column "y" that will populate from either our1, our2, our3, our4, or our5 based on the value in "x." If the value of x is 1, y will take the value of our1; if the value of "x" is 2, y will take the value of our2; and so on. For the example above, it would populate in this way:

```
x   our1    our2    our3    our4    our5    y
4   10      50      40      30      20      30
1   20      10      50      40      30      20
3   30      20      10      50      40      10
2   40      30      20      10      50      30
5   50      40      30      20      10      10
```

Here is the code I am using:

```
df$y <- NA
df$y[df$x==1]<-df$our1[df$x==1]
df$y[df$x==2]<-df$our2[df$x==2]
df$y[df$x==3]<-df$our3[df$x==3]
df$y[df$x==4]<-df$our4[df$x==4]
df$y[df$x==5]<-df$our5[df$x==5]
```

But when I use this code, it populates values from the wrong column in the new column y. In reality, I have 22 columns that my code is supposed to pull from. But only the values from our1 go to column y in the correct rows. the values of our2 go to rows that have x=12, the values of our3 got to rows with x=16, the values of our4 go to rows with x=17, etc.

Is there something that I'm doing wrong with the code? Any ideas on what the problem is and how I can fix it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this easily with `row/column` indexing.  Use the 'x' column as column index, `cbind` with the sequence of rows to extract the element from the subset of dataset (without the 'x' column - `df[-1]`)

```
df$y <- df[-1][cbind(1:nrow(df), df$x)]
df$y
#[1] 30 20 10 30 10
```

Comment: thanks @akrun. i tried that strategy but it didn't seem to work. I have a dataset of 1880 rows and many columns. I subsetted the dataset to only the x column and the 22 "our" columns (i.e. our1, our2, our3, etc.). I then tried to populate the y column with: 

df$y <- df[-1][cbind(1:nrow(df), df$x)] 

like you suggested. But when I try to view the first 5 rows, it gives me this error: 
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function ‘as.item’ for signature ‘"list"’. Any ideas of what might be going wrong?

Comment: @tlev  I think you may have subsetted the wrong columns.  I think you need instead of `df[-1]` i.e. `df[grep("our", names(df))]`

Comment: thanks @akrun. I just used this command:   df$y <- df[grep("our", names(df))][cbind(1:nrow(df), df$x)] but I still received the same error when I attempt to view first 5 rows of the new column. I have never used cbind in this way before. I don't understand from this code, how it knows which column to draw from. Does it look at the number in column x and then find a column name that has that number to choose which column to draw from?

Comment: @tlev  I can only comment based on your description.  If there is something wrong in your description, it won't work.  Anyway, this works for the example and is general if the description is right

Comment: @tlev Do you have `numeric` class in 'x' or not?

Comment: wow @akrun. you solved my problem! That was the issue. I'm using survey data and my x column was a "double.item". I made it numeric and now it's working. Thank you!!